# spring data rest last modified header not getting populated

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Hi I have configured my app as per https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/headers but when I check the responses to my entities the last modified header is not coming even though I have setup everything correctly .
Code below
domain class

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "SHORES_TBL")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Shores {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ShoresKey key;

    /* some fields */

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("shoreId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "shore_id", columnDefinition = "varchar2(12)")
    private Fund fund;

    private @JsonIgnore @LastModifiedDate Date updTs;

}
```

spring boot application config

```
@SpringBootApplication
// Explicitly enable entity links as Boot fails to auto-configure them
@EnableEntityLinks
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class Services extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
/** 
some config

**/
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Services.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {

        return builder.sources(Services.class);
    }
}
```

but in the test cases I am not getting the LAST_MODIFIED header

```
MockHttpServletResponse response = mvc.perform(get(uri)).//
        andDo(print()).//
        andReturn().getResponse();
```

pom config

```
<properties>
    <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Gosling-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.0.RC1</spring.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-hateoas.version>0.18.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-hateoas.version>
    <json-path.version>1.2.0</json-path.version>
</properties>
```

any idea what I am missing here the updTs is in the db and is populated as the updated timestamp .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It finally worked seems I was using the wrong version switched to spring boot 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and now it works like a charm .

use POM

```
<dependencyManagement>
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```